# Plot in R with different pch's

Tags: r, plot

This is my data, and I need to plot:

```
data=structure(c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 
0.1, 0.11, 0.12, 0.13, 0.14, 0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.18, 0.19, 0.2, 
0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 0.24, 0.25, 0.26, 0.27, 0.28, 0.29, 0.3, 0.31, 
0.32, 0.33, 0.34, 0.35, 0.36, 0.37, 0.38, 0.39, 0.4, 0.41, 0.42, 
0.43, 0.44, 0.45, 0.46, 0.47, 0.48, 0.49, 0.5, 0.51, 0.52, 0.53, 
0.54, 0.55, 0.56, 0.57, 0.58, 0.59, 0.6, 0.61, 0.62, 0.63, 0.64, 
0.65, 0.66, 0.67, 0.68, 0.69, 0.7, 0.71, 0.72, 0.73, 0.74, 0.75, 
0.76, 0.77, 0.78, 0.79, 0.8, 0.81, 0.82, 0.83, 0.84, 0.85, 0.86, 
0.87, 0.88, 0.89, 0.9, 0.91, 0.92, 0.93, 0.94, 0.95, 0.96, 0.97, 
0.98, 0.99, -4.29168871465397, -3.11699074587972, 1.09152409255126, 
1.55755175826356, -0.172913268677486, 0.138305902738217, -0.38707713636532, 
0.0638896647028127, 0.838910810102289, 0.943154102106711, 1.10825647675154, 
1.26151733689579, 0.95610404139547, 1.13671597066802, 1.06145162449853, 
1.22015975232484, 1.47211564748976, 1.43575780356999, 1.84397139393396, 
1.76431139003358, 1.59262327273733, 1.74799121927712, 1.60092115463811, 
1.91302749514369, 1.69691050471565, 1.73871696181996, 1.70008388736007, 
1.62139419455853, 2.03803222390097, 1.95654400666235, 2.14213709053145, 
2.20797610828818, 2.43019994960532, 2.43201814098108, 1.80396697393168, 
2.22800019319471, 2.07590961781243, 1.93938306553876, 1.95940985069043, 
2.01357121475676, 1.97530323680977, 1.80327169854223, 2.36734705989908, 
2.44766094824079, 2.75792381459726, 2.77274665368527, 2.49888229303308, 
2.31540449224314, 2.6409962540336, 2.43729957198807, 2.63155885389867, 
2.53653088267223, 2.36871141172942, 2.54858578120089, 2.69802567434559, 
3.09606341962321, 3.08856133175863, 3.18997559061186, 3.36005160648579, 
3.56895022380044, 3.73753226001724, 3.74662085372188, 4.01296134301718, 
4.07267448537225, 3.88165588983999, 3.7369314477271, 3.23912007937852, 
3.31721703890831, 3.21894991022748, 3.48377059081018, 3.32624243338278, 
3.31970136033168, 3.33053692253337, 3.34467916673038, 3.236168836409, 
2.93429043790414, 2.9303837626847, 3.15769722112212, 3.75496410153913, 
3.60526854720219, 3.82913260531081, 4.12105540857576, 4.00407286724511, 
3.86329120505831, 4.01282715673454, 4.27078090625557, 3.57982245847814, 
3.42938648057264, 3.04047099021105, 3.22396221972667, 4.4317374989557, 
4.55399628631069, 4.51384672365535, 5.19575483872483, 4.77975901314362, 
3.67143455937258, 4.83321942758713, 5.82353153779422, 5.4721995802281, 
0.209205679527393, 0.36810747913542, 0.767214115569449, 0.631134464438132, 
0.950471080949761, 0.955883872576242, 0.861939569072133, 0.978322788509546, 
0.650739708163536, 0.609454620741533, 0.416316714902356, 0.424390227854642, 
0.509471258981771, 0.45111061569788, 0.482703338045896, 0.415503380452312, 
0.281397009944395, 0.312633722543431, 0.172403050166603, 0.157569155616774, 
0.223315461391016, 0.134712102225702, 0.187843250166637, 0.109294406499708, 
0.115163596824693, 0.138462578171918, 0.119131458337016, 0.174760537513378, 
0.060100726330413, 0.0724953102167094, 0.0727020992861007, 0.0538763524104828, 
0.0305519665256373, 0.0458544145004334, 0.13222239331969, 0.062914362547982, 
0.0997526784831062, 0.11462977656091, 0.116582141802293, 0.0986337165111772, 
0.136226138825677, 0.168342590268618, 0.0716128991576213, 0.0676036354494944, 
0.0357838762803169, 0.0334279079582225, 0.0610644117339305, 0.0616823286482187, 
0.0660736255131733, 0.104368782129991, 0.0705141118177286, 0.0778176025258217, 
0.108146014569371, 0.125671355892738, 0.0590267483041353, 0.0294699796128093, 
0.0338205013760269, 0.0269159737669502, 0.0134643988629253, 0.00867709725404753, 
0.00493722923021656, 0.00323813401160211, 0.000497278521965683, 
0.000424360028534299, 0.000603507667276793, 0.00192008642195063, 
0.00578745302404915, 0.00632637091749721, 0.0036673526900235, 
0.00322317560117313, 0.00315464572099522, 0.00890662685249866, 
0.00630278028858244, 0.00172069402847441, 0.00297661131713389, 
0.00907593497087, 0.00794661797866469, 0.00360198056893646, 0.000913572843050492, 
0.000952621690864408, 0.000214234772719202, 4.55598611162067e-05, 
2.0600933563486e-05, 0.00014372066333701, 3.00102200614383e-05, 
1.97046007623936e-05, 0.000349337120439941, 0.00580915934418336, 
0.0186446024343607, 0.0455194395151208, 0.0067650312952201, 0.00903110379061256, 
0.0210099376843247, 0.0126330025977033, 0.0735408204027586, 0.158374400655879, 
0.0970807294810527, 0.0643407704341705, 0.408677400389109), .Dim = c(99L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("betas.position", "coef", "pvalue"
)))
```

I need to plot a graph like this: `plot(data[,1],data[,2], pch=8)`

When the p-value `(data[,3])` is bigger than `0.10`, `pch` should be empty(a line).

I believe that I have to construct some rule, but I am not able to do this so far.

Comment: pch=ifelse(data[,3] > 0.1, NA, 8) would have 'empty' pch i.e. no points where data[,3] > 0.1, but I'm confused about where the line comes in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `ifelse`, which returns a vector which here is either 1 or 2 depending on the value of `data[,3]`:

```
plot(data[,1],data[,2],pch=ifelse(data[,3]>0.10,1,2))
```

so `pch=1` for `data[,3]>0` and `pch=2` otherwise. Adjust these for whichever symbols you want, or use NA for nothing. You can use similar logic for setting the symbol size with the `cex=` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The below will remove the points you don't want from your chart:

`data <- as.data.frame(data)
 plot(data[data$pvalue > 0.1,1],data[data$pvalue > 0.1,2], pch=8)`

I'm not sure what you mean by "empty (a line)". If you want to overlay different plot types you should consider ggplot2. It has far more functionality than the Base R plots.